# import sklearn module sklearn has no attribute metrics

Tags: python, scikit-learn

when we use sklearn,

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
```

why we can use only this way to caluate mse?

```
import sklearn

sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error
```

why this way can not? and The compiler will report an error(module sklearn has no attribute metrics).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible in both the ways to find mean_squared_error. For you, the compiler has reported an error because you havenot specified any attributes. I hope below example helps you

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
Y_true = [1,1,2,2,4]  # Y_true = Y (original values)
Y_pred = [0.6,1.29,1.99,2.69,3.4]  # Y_pred = Y'
# Calculation of Mean Squared Error (MSE)
mean_squared_error(Y_true,Y_pred)
```

or

```
import sklearn
# Given values
Y_true = [1,1,2,2,4]  # Y_true = Y (original values)
Y_pred = [0.6,1.29,1.99,2.69,3.4]  # Y_pred = Y'
# Calculation of Mean Squared Error (MSE)
sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error(Y_true,Y_pred)
```

[You can refer my Example by clicking this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTg69.png)

Comment: thanks for your answer, In your second way, The compiler will also report an error like below picture.                                                                                                                                               
![Valid XHTML] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ay0iV.png).

Comment: @JasonLee5555 In your case, i think subpackages has not imported automatically, my be due to your software version. So definitely you have to follow the first approach. I have added an image file in my above comment which worked for me in both the case. You could refer it

Answer (score 0):

```
from sklearn import metrics
yy=neigh.predict(x_train)
print('train set accuracy:',metrics.acuuracy_score(y_train,neigh.predict(x_train))
print('test set acuuracy:',metrics.acuuracy_score(y_test,y_hat))

error:----> 3 print('train set accuracy:',metrics.acuuracy_score(y_train,neigh.predict(x_train)))
      4 print('test set acuuracy:',metrics.acuuracy_score(y_test,y_hat))
```

Produces the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'sklearn.metrics' has no attribute 'acuuracy_score'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34485676)